# ConcurrentModificationException persisting even with ListIterator

Tags: java

I'm doing a library system on Java. I have a class called **Things** with two children: **Print** and **Digital**. **Print** is then divided into **Book** and **Periodical**.

The following is a snippet of the code I wrote to print items. The full code has imports.

```
public class Collection
{
    private ArrayList <Things> theCollection;
    private ListIterator <Things> listItr;

    public Collection ()
    {
        theCollection = new ArrayList <> ();
        listItr = theCollection.listIterator ();
    }

    public void get ()
    {
        Things sThing;
        Book sBook;
        Periodical sPeriodical;
        Digital sDigital;

        sThing = listItr.next ();
        if (sThing instanceof Book)
        {
            sBook = (Book) sThing;
            sBook.bookInfo ();
        }
        else if (sThing instanceof Periodical)
        {
            sPeriodical = (Periodical) sThing;
            sPeriodical.periodicalInfo ();
        }
        else if (sThing instanceof Digital)
        {
            sDigital = (Digital) sThing;
            sDigital.digitalInfo ();
        }
    }

    public void printAll ()
    {
        while (listItr.hasNext ())
            get ();
    }
}
```

I have a problem on the following statement in the get() method:

```
sThing = listItr.next ();
```

When I ran the code, it gave me a ConcurrentModificationException. I tried to search for answers online, but all of them suggested to use an iterator, and I have that. Where did I do wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How (and when) are items added to the list?

Comment: Could you share bookInfo () method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The problem**

You create/request an iterator while constructing your class, directly after creating the list. At this point the list will be empty.

I assume that you afterwards add/remove elements to/from that list. This is a *concurrent modification* because the iterator constrains the iteration to happen on an unmodified list after its creation. The next call to the iterator will then throw this exception.

**The solution**

Don't create the iterator in the constructor of your class. Create it at the needed time:

```
public class Collection {
    private ArrayList <Things> theCollection;

    public Collection () {
        theCollection = new ArrayList <> ();
    }

    public void get () {
        ...
        ListIterator <Things> listItr = theCollection.listIterator();
        sThing = listItr.next ();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

the problem lies in the constructor:

```
public Collection ()
{
    theCollection = new ArrayList <> ();
    listItr = theCollection.listIterator ();
}
```

you are creating a ListIterator before adding elements to the list; in order to avoid the error you must create the iterator just before iterating over the elements;  so remove the iterator creation in the conustructor and place in just before you need it; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421411/problems-with-listiterator-and-concurrent-modification-exception) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496180/concurrent-modification-exception) for similar questions.